# Why my associative array is converted to object PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I am creating an associative array like this

```
public function getEnumFlag(){
    $enums = Category::getPossibleEnumValues('flag');

    $enumArray = array();

    foreach($enums as $enum){
        $enumArray[$enum] = $enum;
    }

    return $enumArray;
}
```

And then I asign the return value to an object.

```
$flags = $this->getEnumFlag();
        
$options = (object) array(
    "flags" => $flags,
);
```

What I got is this.

```
"flags": [
     {
         "General": "General",
         "Article": "Article",
         "Link": "Link",
         "Blog": "Blog"
     }
 ]
```

The expected is.

```
"flags": [
    "General": "General",
    "Article": "Article",
     "Link": "Link",
     "Blog": "Blog"
 ]
```

I don't know why is changing the associative array to an object my version of php is 7.4, also I'm new to php sorry if not using the correct terminology.

Comment: JSON doesn't have associative arrays, they use objects for that

Comment: Thank you, it's true

Comment: You're generating/initializing your array here... $enums = Category::getPossibleEnumValues('flag'); Can you supply code for that method?

Comment: The problem was solved @lagbox was rigth JSON doesn't have associative arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lagbox said:

> JSON doesn't have associative arrays, they use objects for that